# send http request to angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, p2p

I know how to send an http request to a server using angular js. With the `promise` returned, I know how to listen for a `response` and manipulate the ui thereafter. But this approach cannot be used for what I have in mind.

However, what I cannot figure out, is how to send a request to a website.

I have a server `localhost:800/receiveData` which receives a `POST` request and then manipulate the UI and DoM on the angularjs site

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html')
})

app.post('/receiveData', function(req,res){
    var data = req.body.data
    // assume data is a boolean

    if(data){
        //show a view in index.html using angular js or anything else
    }else {
        //show a different view in index.html
    }
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have a need for angular js. Having a SPA is imperative. I am completely open to adding additional stacks if neccessary.

EDIT:
As pointed out by MarcoS, manipulation of dom should ideally not happen from the server side. I am combining `IPFS` with `node js` and `angular js` to develop a single page application. The swarm of nodes set up using `IPFS` has an open line of communication with my server (by design). Based on packets of data sent via the comm line to my server, I need to convey messages to the user via the `index.html`.

Comment: you would really have to decide who does the job of view templating - serverside or front end.

Comment: Are you asking how to update the view on the client in response to a **different** client making an HTTP request to the server? As, for example, you might want for a chat system (so Bob sends a chat message to the server and then the server tells Alice's browser there is a new message and it should update the display)?

Comment: something like that could work. I have experimented a bit with `socket.io` . What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is wrong: on *server-side*, you should **NOT** manipulate the UI and DOM...
You should just do *server* activity (update a database, send an email, ..., return a *static* page).
Then you can output a result (JSON/XML/... format) for your *client-side* calling script to read.

Following OP edit, what I do understand is he wants server **push** to the client.
To get serve side pushes, you should *poll* on the client.
In a controller:

```
function getServerState(changeState) {
  return $http.get("/receiveData").then(function(res) {
    changeState(res.data); // notify the watcher
  }).catch(function(e) {
    /* handle errors here */
  }).then(function() {
    return getServerState(changeState); // poll again when done call
  });
}
```

Consuming it this way:

```
getServerState(function(status) {
  $scope.foo = status; // changes to `foo` $scope variable will reflect instantly on the client
});
```

And, server side:

```
app.post('/receiveData', function(req, res) {
  var data = req.body.data; // assume data is a boolean
  res.end(JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

Comment: I am trying to combine `IPFS` nodes with `nodejs` and `angularjs`. The `IPFS` node can only communicate via an open line of communication with the server. I have added an Edit with a better explanation. Would really like if you could see it. Thanks

Comment: I see. Updating my answer.